yield return new WaitForSeconds() not working
I have this code, but it is don`t waiting in WaitForSeconds(), only
Debug.Log("Starting hit animation");
otherAnimator.SetBool("isHitten", true);
is being completed

using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pikes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage = 1;
    public float speed;
    public GameObject effect;
    GameObject player;
    Animator otherAnimator;

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        otherAnimator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * speed);

         if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {

            otherAnimator.SetBool("isHitten", false);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(HandleHitAnimation());
            other.GetComponent<Player>().health -= damage;
            Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator HandleHitAnimation()
     {
        Debug.Log("Starting hit animation");
        otherAnimator.SetBool("isHitten", true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
       Debug.Log("Ending hit animation");
        otherAnimator.SetBool("isHitten", false);
     }
}


Help to fix this and make waitforseconds work.

what exactly is otherAnimator attached to? Would maybe make sense to rather have a dedicated MonoBehaviour attached to that other object and rather run the coroutine there

StartCoroutine(HandleHitAnimation());

This starts the coroutine on the game-object that the "Pikes" script is attached to. The coroutine is then run every frame at specified times, when it is this objects turn to be updated (simplified).
Destroy(gameObject);

Right below, after starting the coroutine, you destroy the gameObject that it is executed on. Meaning, the coroutine will be destroyed as well, and never get a chance to execute. Eigther destroy the gameObject later, or execute the coroutine on another gameObject that is not destroyed at this point.

I concur. As your code is written the computer is just a touch quicker to Destroy the object than the coroutine is to run (like, 1 second quicker). It races the Destroy command ahead of the command to pause the coroutine (I don't think the coroutine even gets to the starting line TBH). You are going to instantiate your hit effect in OnTriggerEnter no matter what happens. Why not stick that command directly into the coroutine along with Destroy(x); like so:
if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            other.GetComponent<Player>().health -= damage;
            StartCoroutine(HandleHitAnimation());
        }
private IEnumerator HandleHitAnimation()
     {
        Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        otherAnimator.SetBool("isHitten", true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        otherAnimator.SetBool("isHitten", false);
        Destroy(gameObject);
     }

See if that cleans up things. If not, set the Destroy command aside and call it from somewhere else after these functions execute.
Happy clackin', Dude.

probably not desired that an object lingers around once it has been hit already ... your player could collide with it multiple times leading to undesired behavior

I just make that in Player script when he went into Pike collider and that`s worked xD :), thank you all!

Provide a code sample illustrating the solution so that it will be of some help for future viewer's
